# How to create folder in NSLibraryDirectory in mac

Tags: ios, osx-lion

Im trying to create an folder in user library directory,but its not creating. Is there any mistake in the below code.

```
databaseName = @"KITSMAW0051_DB.sqlite";
// Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folder = @"Swasstik";
databasePath = [[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:folder ] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first of all `databasePath` describes a path to a file not a directory. But let's say you actually want to create "Swasstik" folder inside user's Library:

```
// Your code
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folder = @"Swasstik";
// I edited here to keep only the folder
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:folder];

// At this point we got the path to the folder
// but we want to actually go on and create it
// NSFileManager to the rescue!
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager createDirectoryAtPath: folderPath
 withIntermediateDirectories: NO
 attributes: nil
 error: nil];
```

Of course you can [study](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and set the manager as you like and also implement some error handling. I hope that this makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

```
databaseName = @"KITSMAW0051_DB.sqlite";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folder = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Swasstik"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folder]) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
}
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Some error: %@", error);
    return;
}
NSString *databasePath = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```